# NSTokenField: How to get Selected Tokens text?

Tags: objective-c, macos

I hope you can help me as I cannot retrieve the text from an NSTokenField using the following logic. The issue I am experiencing with this code is that it will return to me the full string of all the tokens. I want to be able to only retrieve the text that has been selected by the user. Can this be done ?

```
- (IBAction)onRemoveSelectedCategory:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"CategoryTokenField Selection: %@", [_categoryTokenField.selectedCell stringValue]);

}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `representedObject` method of the selectedCell

```
- (IBAction)onRemoveSelectedCategory:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"CategoryTokenField Selection: %@", [_categoryTokenField.selectedCell representedObject]);

}
```

or

```
-(void) onRemoveSelectedCategory:(id)sender
{

    if([sender respondsToSelector:@selector(representedObject)]){

        NSCell *cell = (NSCell *)sender;

        NSString *token = cell.representedObject;

    }

}
```